# What is the @ operator in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

Set the differentiation matrix as A to be N+2 x N+2

```
A = np.zeros((N+2,N+2))
```

Here we set them using a loop, which must be N+1 long (the size of the off diagonals)

```
for i in range(N+1):
    A[i,i+1] =  1./(2*h)
    A[i+1,i] = -1./(2*h)
```

Does `@` mean multiply in this line below?

```
df_cent = A@f(x) # do the multiplication
```

Comment: `@` is matrix multiplication for this specific use case.

Comment: @DavidErickson The use of `@` for matrix multiplication is discussed both in the accepted answer and in other answers on that question.